# How to keep ftp connection alive

Tags: ftp

Some ftp websites have a small time out value. When you do some other jobs, ftp connection dies and you should log in again.

How can I keep my connection alive?

**Edit:**
 It will be appreciated if somebody provide a method for `ftp` command as it is light and easy.

Comment: Why is it important to you to keep the connection alive?  The FTP server drops your connection on purpose so it can serve other clients.  What's wrong with just logging in again?

Comment: On ftp.gigfa.com it gives just 1 min. But you are right, they want to serve other clients. How ever it can be other method to respond users faster and better I think. Anyway I thank the free servers.

Answer (score 4):

There is no absolute answer here, as FTP protocol in itself does not include such a mechanism.

There is however, FTP protocol commands with no real meanings on a given situation like "NOOP", "LIST" or "CWD" which can be used to keep the FTP connection alive.

So this is up to the client itself to implement such a mechanism using these "meaningless" commands in order to reset the timeout timers on the server side. Of course, you might also need to tune these client side mechanism in order to match the server side max idle time value.

To give you an example, the well known [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is implementing such a mechanism (see in "Edit" -> "Settings" menu item, then in "Connection" -> "FTP" tab):

[image: Filezilla Settings]

**Answer to edit**: As said, only evolved ftp client would have such functionality. Default ftp client, Windows and Linux alike, are not able to apply such keep alive behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was appreciated if I find a method for `ftp` command.

Comment: What system are you using (to have some clue about its default ftp client) ?

Comment: I use ftp.gigfa.com. I connect to it using default `ftp` command.

Comment: The remote end doesn't matter much. If your system is Windows and the ftp client is the default ftp command: no luck here. Only advanced ftp client would have this feature.

Comment: My OS is Linux.

Comment: The default ftp client for linux is bit more potent than the Windows one. Try the "idle" command to see if you can change the server timeout value, but I really doubt it. Big chance it is not supported at all.